# Create functors from functions with unknown argument count

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I wrote a program in C++ & boost. Is it possible to write a template class producing functors from functions with an unknown number of arguments, e.g. `my_call<func>(vector<variant>)`, where fun can be `bool fun(string)` or `bool fun(int, int, string)`, etc.?

Comment: Can you give a sample use case? I don't quite understand your specification. Is `my_call` the class and it overloads `operator()`? Are the elements of the `vector` passed as arguments? Will you call the functor with just empty parentheses?

Comment: I have hashtable of callbacks using function pointers `event_N(vector<variant> params)`. I would like to declare event functions in a normal way, like `event_N(string param1, int param2)` etc., and push functors to hashtable. Templates could help me not to write each functor class manually.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that `variant` must specify which types it can hold? So it's not just `variant` but `variant<int, string, bool>` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is important to recognize that `boost::variant<>` is a class template that requires the list of all the possible types it can hold. So, you won't have just a `vector<variant>`, but rather a `vector<variant<string, double>>`, or `vector<variant<int, double, string, my_class>>`, and you won't be able to mix them.

This made me think you might want to use `boost::any` rather than `boost::variant<>`. Thus, I present here a solution that works with `boost::variant` and can be slightly modified to use `boost::any`, so you can pick the version you prefer.

---

To begin with, I must admit that the solution is **simple to use** but *not so simple to understand*, so I will have to introduce some **machinery** first. This machinery is **common** to both the variant-based and the any-based solution.

```
//=============================================================================
// META-FUNCTIONS FOR CREATING INDEX LISTS

// The structure that encapsulates index lists
template <size_t... Is>
struct index_list
{
};

// Collects internal details for generating index ranges [MIN, MAX)
namespace detail
{
    // Declare primary template for index range builder
    template <size_t MIN, size_t N, size_t... Is>
    struct range_builder;

    // Base step
    template <size_t MIN, size_t... Is>
    struct range_builder<MIN, MIN, Is...>
    {
        typedef index_list<Is...> type;
    };

    // Induction step
    template <size_t MIN, size_t N, size_t... Is>
    struct range_builder : public range_builder<MIN, N - 1, N - 1, Is...>
    {
    };
}

// Meta-function that returns a [MIN, MAX) index range
template<size_t MIN, size_t MAX>
using index_range = typename detail::range_builder<MIN, MAX>::type;
```

The meta-class `index_range` allows defining **compile-time sequences of integers**. [An interesting proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3493.html) have been made by [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) to standardize this kind of construct, so that this whole machinery would not be needed. For the moment, however, we have to hand code this as done above.

---

Now that we can build compile-time integer sequences, we can exploit **variadic templates** and **argument unpacking** to create a dispatching mechanism that translates a vector of `variant` arguments into a regular argument list. Notice how the concrete `variant<>` type must be provided as a template argument. This will *not* be needed for the solution based on `any`.

```
// Headers needed for the implementation of the dispatcher
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

// Just for convenience
using namespace std;
using boost::variant;

//============================================================================
// DISPATCHER IMPLEMENTATION

// Call dispatching mechanism: notice how the underlying variant type
// must be provided as a template argument (the first one)
template<typename VT, typename R, typename... Args>
struct dispatcher
{

    template<typename F>
    dispatcher(F f) : _f(f) { }

    // The call operator which performs the variant dispatch
    R operator () (vector<VT> const& v)
    {
        if (v.size() != sizeof...(Args))
        {
            // Wrong number of arguments provided!
            return false;
        }

        // Delegates to internal function call: needed for deducing
        // a sequence of integers to be used for unpacking.
        index_range<0, sizeof...(Args)> indexes;
        return do_call(v, indexes);
    }

private:

    // The heart of the dispatching mechanism
    template<size_t... Is>
    R do_call(vector<VT> const& v, index_list<Is...> indexes)
    {
        return _f((get_ith<Args>(v, Is))...);
    }

    // Helper function that extracts a typed value from the variant.
    template<typename T>
    T get_ith(vector<VT> const& v, size_t i)
    {
        return boost::get<T>(v[i]);
    }

    // Wrapper that holds the function to be invoked.
    function<R(Args...)> _f;
};

// Helper function that allows deducing the input function signature
template<typename VT, typename R, typename... Args>
function<R (vector<VT> const&)> get_dispatcher(R (*f)(Args...))
{
    dispatcher<VT, R, Args...> d(f);
    return d;
}
```

Finally, a short demonstration of how you could use this. Suppose we have two test functions such as the ones below:

```
#include <iostream>

bool test1(string s, double d)
{
    cout << s << " " << d << endl;
    return true;
}

bool test2(int i1, int i2, string s1, string s2)
{
    cout << i1 << " " << i2 << " " << s1 << " " << s2 << endl;
    return true;
}
```

What we want is to invoke them by building a vector of variants and have it dispatched to the desired function. Once again, I must stress the fact that *we need to specify the list of all the types our variant can hold*. Here, I will assume these types are `string`, `double`, and `int`, but your program might work with different ones.

Also, the solution is based on `std::function<>` for realizing the type erasure that allows you creating functors of different types and yet invoke them uniformly. Thus, a convenience type definition for this `std::function<>` (which in turn depends on the `variant<>` type we use) is provided as well:

```
int main()
{
    // A helper type definition for the variant
    typedef variant<int, double, string> vt;

    // A helper type definition for the function wrapper
    typedef function<bool (vector<vt>)> dispatcher_type;

    // Get a caller for the first function
    dispatcher_type f1 = get_dispatcher<vt>(test1);

    // Prepare arguments for the first function
    vector<vt> v = {"hello", 3.14};

    // Invoke the first function
    f1(v);

    // Get a caller for the second function
    dispatcher_type f2 = get_dispatcher<vt>(test2);

    // Prepare arguments for the second function
    v.assign({1, 42, "hello", "world"});

    // Invoke the second function
    f2(v);
}
```

Since all dispatchers have type `dispatcher_type`, you can easily **put them into a container**. However, you must be aware of the fact that attempts to invoke a function with the *wrong number of arguments* will be detected only at *run-time* (it is impossible to know at compile-time how many elements an `std::vector<>` contains). Thus, proper care must be taken.

---

As promised, I will now slightly modify this solution to use `boost::any` rather than `boost::variant`. The advantage is that since `boost::any` can hold *any* value, it is **not necessary** to specify the list of the possible types which can be used as function arguments.

While the helper machinery is unchanged, the core dispatcher class template must be modified as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::any;

//=============================================================================
// DISPATCHER IMPLEMENTATION

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct dispatcher
{

    template<typename F>
    dispatcher(F f) : _f(f) { }

    // The call operator which performs the dispatch
    R operator () (vector<any> const& v)
    {
        if (v.size() != sizeof...(Args))
        {
            // Wrong number of arguments provided!
            return false;
        }

        // Delegates to internal function call: needed for deducing
        // a sequence of integers to be used for unpacking.
        index_range<0, sizeof...(Args)> indexes;
        return do_call(v, indexes);
    }

private:

    // The heart of the dispatching mechanism
    template<size_t... Is>
    R do_call(vector<any> const& v, index_list<Is...> indexes)
    {
        return _f((get_ith<Args>(v, Is))...);
    }

    // Helper function that extracts a typed value from the variant.
    template<typename T>
    T get_ith(vector<any> const& v, size_t i)
    {
        return boost::any_cast<T>(v[i]);
    }

    // Wrapper that holds the function to be invoked.
    function<R(Args...)> _f;
};

// Helper function
template<typename R, typename... Args>
function<R (vector<any> const&)> get_dispatcher(R (*f)(Args...))
{
    dispatcher<R, Args...> d(f);
    return d;
}
```

As you see, the `VT` template argument has vanished. In particular, it is possible to call `get_dispatcher` without explicitly specifying any template argument. Using the same test functions we have defined for the `variant`-based solution, here is how you would adapt the `main()` routine:

```
int main()
{
    // Helper type definition
    typedef function<bool (vector<any>)> dispatcher_type;

    // Get a caller for the first function
    dispatcher_type f1 = get_dispatcher(test1);

    // Get a caller for the second function
    dispatcher_type f2 = get_dispatcher(test2);
    // Prepare arguments for the first function

    vector<any> v = {string("hello"), 3.14};

    // Invoke the first function
    f1(v);

    // Prepare arguments for the second function
    v.assign({1, 42, string("hello"), string("world")});

    // Invoke the second function
    f2(v);
}
```

The only disadvantage is that with `boost::any` you cannot assign string literals explicitly, because string literals are of type `char []`, and arrays cannot be used to initialize objects of type `any`:

```
any a = "hello"; // ERROR!
```

Thus, you have to either wrap them into `string` objects, or explicitly convert them to a pointer to `char const*`:

```
any a = string("hello"); // OK
any b = (char const*)"hello"; // OK
```

If this is not a huge problem for you, it's probably better to go for this second solution.

Comment: no matching function for call «dispatcher<const string&, const string&>::do_call(const std::vector<boost::variant<int, const string&> >&, index_range<0u, 2ul>&)»
candidate is:
template<long unsigned int ...Is> bool dispatcher::do_call(const std::vector<boost::variant<int, const string&> >&, index_list<Is ...>) [with long unsigned int ...Is = {Is ...}; Args = {const string&, const string&}]
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
mismatched types «long unsigned int» and #«integer_cst not supported by dump_type#<type error>
index_list<0u, 1u> is not derived from index_list<Is ...>

Comment: @user1528805: How about explaining a bit better, rather than dumping a compiler error at me? Which of the two versions are you using? What compiler are you using, and what version?

Comment: @user1528805: Btw the problem was likely in the use of `unsigned int` instead of `size_t`. I edited the code, just try it out.